# Algorithm to add all lucky numbers under [N] to a Vector

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, c++11

> A lucky number is defined as a positive integer whose decimal representation contains only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not. I need to check if a given number is evenly divisible by any lucky number or not.
>
> Now, suppose I want to add all Lucky Numbers under a given integer [N] to a vector, without using recursion. For the sake of simplicity, let N = 1000.

I came up with an approach to just check each digit of all the numbers under [N] by making separate loops for 1 digit numbers, 2 digit numbers etc.

```
for(int number=0;number<10;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //1 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=10;number<100;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //2 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=100;number<1000;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //3 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=10;number<100;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))&&(((number/1000)%10==7)||((number/1000)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //4 Digit Lucky Numbers
```

I was thinking that this could roughly be converted to something along these lines but I am not quite able to come up with what exactly to do.

```
for(number;number<10*itr_counter;number++)
    {
    if(((number%10*itr_counter==4)||(number%10*itr_counter==7))) {lucky.push_back(number);}
    itr_counter*=10;
    }
```

I basically want to check each digit of all 1 digit numbers by taking modulo 10 and checking if the digits are 4 or 7. Similarly for a number consisting of X digits, I am taking modulo and dividing the number by 10, 100 and so on to check against 4 or 7.

Can someone help me optimise the first block of code into something smaller and more efficient? Something along the lines of the second block of code would work.

**The Program**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int in_num;
cin>>in_num;

//This Part Needs to be Optimised
vector<int>lucky;
for(int number=0;number<10;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //1 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=10;number<100;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //2 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=100;number<1000;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //3 Digit Lucky Numbers
for(int number=10;number<100;number++) {if(((number%10==4)||(number%10==7))&&(((number/10)%10==7)||((number/10)%10==4))&&(((number/100)%10==7)||((number/100)%10==4))&&(((number/1000)%10==7)||((number/1000)%10==4))) {lucky.push_back(number);}} //4 Digit Lucky Numbers
//This Part Needs to be Optimised

int flag=0;
for(unsigned int index=0;index<lucky.size();index++)
    {
    if(in_num%lucky[index]==0) {flag=1; break;}
    }
if(flag==1) {cout<<"YES";}
else {cout<<"NO";}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to generate a vector with all the values.  First, you should treat all the same length numbers as a group.  The values 4 and 7 would be in a singledigit vector.  To get the twodigit vector, simply go through the previous vector, multiplying each by 10 and then adding 4 to push back a value and add 7 to push back another value.

```
vector<int> lucky;
vector<int> current;
vector<int> next;
current.push_back(4);
current.push_back(7);
lucky.push_back(4);
lucky.push_back(7);
int value=0;
while(value < N)
{
   for(unsigned int i=0;i<current.size();++i)
   {
       value=current[i]*10+4;
       next.push_back(value);
       lucky.push_back(value);
       value=current[i]*10+7;
       next.push_back(value);
       lucky.push_back(value);
   }

   current=next;
   next.clear();
}
```

Comment: I would only use a single vector, but otherwise good work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's lots to improve about your program.

1. Consider adopting any of the common styles for code-formatting.
   As-is, your current formatting seriously impedes readability.
2. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is a bad idea, sharply limiting portability and increasing compile-times. See: [How does `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` work in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25311011)
   Just include those headers you need, which are `<vector>` and `<iostream>`.
3. You are courting conflicting symbols and general bafflement with any minor change of your toolchain. See: [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)
4. You are using the popular for-if-antipattern. See [Introducing the for-if anti-pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793)
   Why don't you just enumerate the ones you are actually interested in?
5. A for-range-loop is simpler than explicitly using iterators/indices. Unless you actually need them.
6. In the end you don't actually want that whole list, only whether one of them divides your input-number. So why store them at all, and why also those bigger than the input-number?
7. `return 0;` is implicit for `main` in C++.

Doing it as it should be done, [with recursion on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/509560d255c0f478):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int luckydiv_helper(long in, long num, int free) {
    return !free
        ? !(in % num)
        : luckydiv_helper(in, 10 * num + 4, free - 1)
            || luckydiv_helper(in, 10 * num + 7, free - 1);
}

int luckydiv(long in) {
    long abort = in;
    for(int digits = 1; abort; digits++, abort /= 10)
        if(luckydiv_helper(in, 0, digits))
            return 1;
    return !in;
}

int main() {
    long in;
    if(scanf("%ld", &in) != 1 || in < -999999999 || in > 999999999) {
        fprintf(stderr, "You didn't enter a number between -999999999 and "
            "+999999999. Aborting.\n");
        // A long can represent all 9-digit decimal numbers.
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%ld ", in);
    if(in < 0) in = -in;
    puts(luckydiv(in) ? "YES" : "NO");
}
```

A way to efficiently get all "lucky" numbers without recursion:

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

template<class T> std::vector<T> luckyvector() {
    std::vector<T> v = {4, 7};
    const auto limit4 = (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - 4) / 10;
    const auto limit7 = (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - 7) / 10;
    T x;
    for(size_t i = 0; (x = v[i]) <= limit7; i++) {
        v.push_back(x * 10 + 4);
        v.push_back(x * 10 + 7);
    }
    if(x <= limit4)
        v.push_pack(x * 10 + 4);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: You used recursion in `luckydiv_helper()`, and the task forbids recursion.

Comment: @200_success: I gave a way to do the task the program solves efficiently *with* recursion, yes. And a way to just generate a vector with all those numbers, without recursion. Clarified what is what.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_lucky(int check_num)
{
while(check_num!=0)
    {
    if((check_num%10!=4)&&(check_num%10!=7))
        {
        return false;
        }
    check_num/=10;
    }
return true;
}

int main()
{
std::vector <long long> lucky;
for(int in_num=1;in_num<1000;in_num++)
    {
    if(is_lucky(in_num))
        {
        lucky.push_back(in_num);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I am still using the for-if anti-pattern as Deduplicator pointed out, I was finally able to make the `is_lucky` function which maybe less efficient and a lesser intelligent way to do it than the other ones posted, seems to be the shortest way to do the task.